# Python SyntaxError with format string and object literal

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code produces `SyntaxError`:

```
f'something_{{ 'BEAM': '.', 'GRIN': '.', 'GRIN31': '/' }[coin]}'
```

Is it possible to use object literals this way for an inline "select"?

Comment: Can we have that Dictionary in a variable and use that?

Comment: This? `f"something_{dict([('BEAM', '.'), ('GRIN', '.'), ('GRIN31', '/')])[coin]}"`

Comment: That double `{` is being interpreted as an escape sequence for including a literal curly bracket in your string.  I think inserting a space between them, or putting parentheses around your dictionary literal, would fix this (assuming that you're running a recent enough Python version to even support f-strings, of course).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems.

First, you can't use single quotes in the `dict` display, because the string parser doesn't consider the braces to "separate" them; the first `'` closes the string literal. (Or rather, you need to use different quotes or escape the quotes to avoid unintentionally closing the f-string.)

Second, `{{` is a single literal `{` in an f-string; you need to separate them with a space.

```
>>> coin = "GRIN"
>>> f'something_{ { "BEAM": ".", "GRIN": ".", "GRIN31": "/" }[coin]}'
'something_.'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, here a example:

```
$ test1 = 'abc'
$ test2 = '123'
$ test3= 'foo'
$ coin = 'foo'
f"something_{ { test1: '.', test2: '.', test3: '/' }[coin]}"
>>> something_/
```

on f-string syntax, the brackets is represents by double {{ or }} => { or }, that's why first 2 { has an empty space between them.